# Spring form validation problems

Tags: forms, spring-mvc

I'm writing a web app with spring and I'm having problems with forms validation. It's the first time I use that, so I still have to understand it...

Basically I have a controller with the form handling method that is :

```
@RequestMapping(params = "action=gestprodotti")
    public ModelAndView doGestProdotti(
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(value = "activity", required = false) String activity,
            @ModelAttribute Prodotto prod, BindingResult bindresult,
            HttpSession session) throws Exception {
```

the controller is annotated and doesn't extend anything. Later in the method, after receiving the object bound to the form, I do:

```
Validator valid = activityHandler.getValidator();
            valid.validate(backingObject, bindresult);
            if (bindresult.hasErrors()){
                return handleRequest(action, ACTIVITY_NEW_ITEM, jspComponent,
                        page, itemId, backingObject, bindresult, appstatus);
            }
```

that means that I call manually the validator and give back the same form page (a ModelAndView result).

The validator code:

```
public static final class ProdottoValidator implements Validator{

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> other) {
            return Prodotto.class.isAssignableFrom(other);          
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "codice", "Il codice è richiesto");           
        }

    }
```

and the relevant JSP code:

```
<td colspan="2" align="left">Codice<form:input id="code"
                path="codice" /><form:errors path="codice" /></td>
```

that works fine for binding, but I don't get any error. I didn't create any messages.properties file, but I think I should see something anyway. Errors are detected because `bindresult.hasErrors()` gives true, but the rendered html doesn't show up anything in place of form:errors. Am I missing something like configuration or whatever? Is it because there is not a messages.properties file that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical symptom of model attribute name mismatch.

Model attribute name should be the same in three places:

1. In form setup method, where you put initial state of the form object into the model.
2. In `<form:form>` element of JSP page. Default name here is `command`, it can be configured using `modelAttribute` attribute (or `commandName`, it's the same thing).
3. In form processing method, such as your `doGestProdotti`. Default name is inferred as an argument class name with the first letter decapitalized (`prodotto` in your case). You can specify the name explicitly with `@ModelAttribute("..."`).

Mismatch between points (2) and (3) causes validation errors not being displayed. Mismatch between points (1) and (2) causes binding errors when displaying a form.

So, you need either to configure `prodotto` as a model attribute name in points (1) and (2)

```
<form:form modelAttribute = "prodotto" ...>
    ....
    <form:errors path="codice" />
    ...
</form:form>
```

or configure `command` as an attribute name in point (3)

```
@ModelAttribute("command") Prodotto prod
```

Comment: default should be "command" as the docs say. Using prodotto as you say ends in a binding error. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @ModelAttribute doesn't get the name attribute, I get an error. prodotto in form:form breaks the binding and causes an exception...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any messages.properties file I would expect there to be an error message in the logs because it can't find any message under the code "Il codice e richiesto".