# Show validation errors in spring3 MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need help.  I want to validate form input with custom validator in Spring 3 MVC.
Every thing is working fine but errors are not being displayed on form in case of error

this is controller

```
public class ContactController {
 @ModelAttribute("Contact")
 public Contact getContactObject() {
      return new Contact();
     }


@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processValidatinForm(@Valid Contact contact, BindingResult result, Map model,Errors e) {
    UserValidator validator = new UserValidator();
      validator.validate(contact, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("found Errors");
        return "contact";
    }
    // Add the saved validationForm to the model
    model.put("Contact", contact);
    return "successs";
}

@RequestMapping("/contacts")
public String showValidatinForm(Map model) {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    model.put("Contact", contact);
    return "contact";
}
```

}
user validator

```
    public class UserValidator implements Validator {

   @Override
        public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
       return Contact.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
   }

   @Override
   public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userName", "Enter user name");
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "age", "Enter Age");
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "Enter password.");

   }

}
```

and this is form jsp page

```
 <form:form method="post" action="addContact.html" commandName="Contact">

<table>

<tr>
<td>User Name:<font color="red"><form:errors path="userName" /></font></td>
```

```
<tr>
<td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Age:<font color="red"><form:errors path="age" /></font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><form:input path="age" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:<font color="red"><form:errors path="password" /></font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><form:password path="password" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form:form>
```

how to do it right?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring form validation problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896367/spring-form-validation-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the validation part is correct . Ensure that you are returning the correct view from the controller in case of errors.

Comment: I have found the bug, code is fine but I added a wrong jar file in the code, now I have removed that jar and code is working fine.
thanks for your help